# Limiting Admin Backend Search to Title

Tags: admin, search

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to limit the search in the WP admin area to just post titles? It's very frustrating to want to pull up a specific page, and get hundreds of results that have that word in the post content.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by altering the search query via the `posts_search` hook.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/query.php#L2202

A default search query will look like this:

`..AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE \'%search terms%\') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE \'%search terms%\')))`

We need to remove the post content search, a regular expression should be enough.

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'wpse_45153_filter_search', null, 2 );
function wpse_45153_filter_search( $search, $a_wp_query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() ) return $search; // work only in the dashboard

    $search = preg_replace( "# OR \(.*posts\.post_content LIKE \\'%.*%\\'\)#", "", $search );

    return $search;
}
```

Note that the regular expression has not been thoroughly tested and may have edge cases when other plugins or themes alter hook into here.

Answer (score 1):

This code working for me :

```
    add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_title_only', 10, 2 );
function search_by_title_only( $search, $wp_query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() || empty( $search ) ){
        return $search;
    }
    global $wpdb;
    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $x = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';
    $search = '';
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
        $term = esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $term ) );
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$x}{$term}{$x}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }
    if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
    }
    return $search;
}
```

Comment: Hello Hayder Hossain, welcome to WordPress SE. It seems you have gotten your answer off to a good start with some functional code. To turn your answer from just okay to truly useful, consider editing to add an explanation of how this solves the question. That way you will have written a timeless and useful answer that allows others to not just solve the problem but understand how the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add this code to your theme’s functions.php file. This code will limit search by post title only.

```
function __search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query ) {
global $wpdb;

if ( empty( $search ) )
    return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query

$q = $wp_query->query_vars;    
$n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';

$search =
$searchand = '';

foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
    $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
    $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
    $searchand = ' AND ';
}

if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
    $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
}

return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );
```